# libGDX buttons work on desktop, but not android

Tags: java, android, debugging, libgdx

For some reason, buttons work on desktop, but when ran on android, pushing the buttons does nothing.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        if(playBounds.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()))
            gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
```

Essentially, there's rectangles the same size as the button, and if you press on the rectangle, it does a certain action. The buttons work perfectly fine on the desktop launcher, but when ran on a phone, the buttons do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to log what happens when you run on Android?

I guess you should use "Gdx.input.isTouched()". But i hardly suggest you to use [InputListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html) with your own InputHandler class.

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {
public InputHandler(GameWorld gameWorld) {
}
}
```